# How to use moment to format to 1pm and 1.30pm if there is minutes?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to use momentjs to format to 1pm when there is no minutes and 1.30pm if there is minutes?

```
let start = MOMENT(startDate).format("MMM D (ddd): h.mma").toString();
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `.replace('.00', '');`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
let date = moment(startDate);
let start = date.get('minutes') === 0 ? date.format("MMM D (ddd): ha") : format("MMM D (ddd): h.mma");
```